# How to use Substring to find a character and update date format?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field in one table named SourceID.  All records have a bunch of '|' characters, and after the last pipe is a date, in four different format.  I am trying to update this date to be in one single format.  The data looks like this.

```
SourceID
ARS|1C47|13.2|2017-09-29
mm|M8|160|030|ZX7|Sep 29 2017 12:00AM
TMP_Schedule | Int | MG100 | 20370429
TS|01|0|USD|I|S|ZDER|10/31/2017
```

I tried to come up with code to update another field (SourceID_Revised), in the same table, with all data from SourceID and one standardized date format, such as DD/MM/YYYY.  I tried some different ideas, and came up with this, which is think is close, but of course it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE    TBL_HIST
SET       SourceID_Revised = SourceID
WHERE     (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), SUBSTRING([SourceID],select dbo.LastIndexOf('|', [SourceID]),99)) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
FROM [dbo].[TBL_HIST]
```

Using this to find the last pipe.

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[LastIndexOf] (@stringToFind varchar(max), @stringToSearch varchar(max))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (LEN(@stringToSearch) - CHARINDEX(@stringToFind,REVERSE(@stringToSearch))) + 1
END
```

I'm on SQL Server 2008.

UPDATE:

John, I think this could work!  It runs for about 5 seconds and then konks out.  I get this message.

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I'm guessing, that because some records in that field have nothing at all like a date.  So I have things like this:

```
40285
3467868
```

I think that is causing an error.  How can I skip those, or just do some  kind of On Error Resume Next?

One more thing that I noticed is that several hundred records have this format.

```
101.002.112020-06-30
102.0012.102019-09-30
125.02.022022-06-30
```

For these, I want to find the last dot, move to to the right, and get

```
MM/DD/YYYY:
06/30/2020
09/30/2019
06/30/2022
```

NOT DD/MM/YY!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not on 2012+, you can't use try_convert()

The following works with the sample provided,  but I have concerns of conversion failures (i.e. bogus dates)

Note, the following can be converted to inline if you can't use or want the Parse UDF.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SourceID] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
('RS|1C47|13.2|2017-09-29'),
('mm|M8|160|030|ZX7|Sep 29 2017 12:00AM'),
('TMP_Schedule | Int | MG100 | 20370429'),
('TS|01|0|USD|I|S|ZDER|10/31/2017')

Update @YourTable Set SourceID=Replace(SourceID,RetVal,AsDate)
  From @YourTable A
  Cross Apply (
                Select Top 1 *,AsDate = convert(varchar(10),convert(Date,RetVal),101)
                 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]([SourceID],'|')
                 Order By RetSeq Desc
               ) B

Select * From  @YourTable
```

**Returns Updated Table**

```
SourceID
RS|1C47|13.2|09/29/2017
mm|M8|160|030|ZX7|09/29/2017
TMP_Schedule | Int | MG100 | 04/29/2037
TS|01|0|USD|I|S|ZDER|10/31/2017
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```